# Should i use CSRF token in Rest api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, csrf

I am creating a login registration system using React on frontend and express js on backend .

In this system i will use access and refresh token . When user logs in that user will get access token which will be stored in memory in React and refresh token will be stored in Http only secure cookie .

But the main thing here is , while user register or login on my website that user will make post request to my backend api via submitting form on my website . Since the user is making post request from react app to backend , should i use CSRF token on my frontend .

Also i am using CORS on backend which will only allow my React app to send request to the backend api . Also Refresh token is stored in http only secured cookie , whenever access token expires i will send a request to refresh token route to get a new pair of access and refresh token . In this case also should i need to send CSRF token to backend .

Please provide your suggestions about it .

Answer (score 0):

This attack is based on cookies, so if you use cookie to auth, it s better to have a CRSF token.

If your token is set in the Authorization header. It s safe. Your navigator wont automatically add the header to auth the request.

But if it s a cookie, the navigator will auth the request automatically.